# Elastic Search 2.4.6 using Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I am using docker to run a Laravel 5.3 project which is using Elastic Search 2.4.6 as a prerequisite, I have tried with 6.4.1 (which is available on docker hub) but unfortunately I got following error:

```
[Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception]                                                                                                              
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [message]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","  
  reason":"Failed to parse mapping [candidates_mapping_beta]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [message]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception"  
  ,"reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [message]"}},"status":400}
```

Here is my current use of Elastic Search image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1 (requirement is 2.4.6)

Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Try `docker pull elasticsearch:2.4.6`  (it uses Dockerfile from https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/8e87587ac5d6b44a8382a229162c88e65618c30a/2.4/Dockerfile)

Comment: nice, I will try it tomorrow mate